# C# Wpf datagrid issue when declaring length of array

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, datagrid

For making it clear, I have 3 arrays. ArrX, ArrY, ArrZ

These will be put into the array: GridArr

What Im trying to do, is a wpf app that will gather information, sort the wanted info into Arr1, Arr2 and Arr3. Put them right inside the GridArr. So it can get loaded into the datagrid. The user can edit and then get the changed values into the same array it once came from. (ArrX, ArrY, ArrZ)

Datagrid visual example:

```
Test    | Dest    | Testy
ArrX[0] | ArrY[0] | ArrZ[0]
ArrX[1] | ArrY[1] | ArrZ[1]
ArrX[2] | ArrY[2] | ArrZ[2]
```

ArrX will be values into Test.
ArrY to Dest etc.

The problem is that I must declare the size of GridArr. And I made a function to return the right size for GridArr, however I cant manage to declare it without having to put the array inside a class (without getting an error), and if GridArr is inside a class I have no clue how I should manage to get the new users edited values into ArrX, ArrY and ArrZ.

```
    string[] ArrX = { "test", "", "asd" };
    int[] ArrY = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int[] ArrZ = {111, 2212, 32323};


    private LootData[] GridArr = new LootData[ArrX.Length]; /* Error occurs.
    What should I do to declare it´s length without writing for example 3 */

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            GridArr[0] = new LootData(ArrX[0], ArrY[0], ArrZ[0]);//Code LootData below
            GridArr[1] = new LootData(ArrX[1], ArrY[1], ArrZ[1]);
            GridArr[2] = new LootData(ArrX[2], ArrY[2], ArrZ[2]);

            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = null;
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = arr;
    }
```

The LootData class, incase someone wants to know what´s behind there.

```
class LootData
{
    private string name;
    private int dest;
    private int id;

    public LootData(string Name, int Dest, int Id)
    {
        name = Name;
        dest = Dest;
        id = Id;
    }

    public string Name 
    {
        get { return name; } 
        set { name = value; } 
    }

    public int Dest
    {
        get { return dest; }
        set { dest = value; }
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

initialize the field `GridArr` in the constructor or in the button event handler

```
private LootData[] GridArr;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    GridArr = new LootData[ArrX.Length];//ArrX.Length is accessible now
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Just 1 question. But then I cant access added values from other button events etc? I dunno if Im looking for a global array or smth, but if there is a way to aovid it I would love to know, since I have heard globals are not recommended.

Comment: you can access it from other methods within the class, since its declared on the class

Comment: you declared the field `GridArr` with `private` accessor, thats means it can be accessed from all methods inside the class, this is normal. i think you mean public fields by `global`, if this what you mean then yes , its not recommended, you could read more about the term `encapsulation` to know why.